# Creating table/grid with Vaadin and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, vaadin

I want to create simply page where the vaadin's grid will be displayed with data from database. Unfortunately I didnt find any solution in documentation or movies... So, I have my JPA class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Movie {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
private String movieName;
@Column
private String description;

public Movie(){}

public Movie(String movieName, String description) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.description = description;
}
```

With all getters and setters. And now I want to create GUI:

```
@Route("show-movies")
public class MovieGUI extends VerticalLayout{}
```

And I tried everything: Grid < Movie>,initializeGrid, but nothing works. I just want to in simple way add 3 columns(name,desc and action) and display data from my db and button to create action. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
@Route("show-movies")
public class MovieGUI extends VerticalLayout{
  MovieGUI(MovieRepository repo) {
    Grid<Movie> movieGrid = new Grid<>();
    movieGrid.setItems(repo.findAll());
    movieGrid.addColumn(Movie::getName).setHeader("Name");
    movieGrid.addColumn(Movie::getDescription).setHeader("Description");
    movieGrid.addComponentColumn(movie -> new NativeButton("Action", click-> doSomething(movie)).setHeader("");
    add(movieGrid);
  }
}
```

Check out the demo sources here for more examples: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples